# Setting Window Location to the same page PHP Shopping Cart

Tags: php, mysql, session

Can someone help me on ow to make Window Location when I click the "Add to Cart" or the remove item button remain to the same page so I can browse for another item easily without going back.

```
<?php
session_start();
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "tut");
if (isset($_POST["add"])) {
  if (isset($_SESSION["cart"])) {
    $item_array_id = array_column($_SESSION["cart"], "product_id");
    if (!in_array($_GET["id"], $item_array_id)) {
      $count = count($_SESSION["cart"]);
      $item_array = array(
        'product_id' => $_GET["id"],
        'item_name' => $_POST["hidden_name"],
        'product_price' => $_POST["hidden_price"],
        'item_quantity' => $_POST["quantity"]
      );
      $_SESSION["cart"][$count] = $item_array;
      echo '<script>window.location="#"</script>';
    } else {
      echo '<script>alert("Products already added to cart")</script>';
      echo '<script>window.location="#.php"</script>';
    }
  } else {
    $item_array = array(
      'product_id' => $_GET["id"],
      'item_name' => $_POST["hidden_name"],
      'product_price' => $_POST["hidden_price"],
      'item_quantity' => $_POST["quantity"]
    );
    $_SESSION["cart"][0] = $item_array;
  }
}
if (isset($_GET["action"])) {
  if ($_GET["action"] == "delete") {
    foreach ($_SESSION["cart"] as $keys => $values) {
      if ($values["product_id"] == $_GET["id"]) {
        unset($_SESSION["cart"][$keys]);
        echo '<script>alert("Product has been removed")</script>';
        echo '<script>window.location="#.php"</script>';
      }
    }
  }
}
?>
```

This is my table showing my Shopping Cart below every pages:

```
<div style="clear:both"></div>
<h2>My Shopping Cart</h2>
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table table-bordered">
    <tr>
      <th width="40%">Product Name</th>
      <th width="10%">Quantity</th>
      <th width="20%">Price Details</th>
      <th width="15%">Order Total</th>
      <th width="5%">Action</th>
    </tr>
    <?php
    if (!empty($_SESSION["cart"])) {
      $total = 0;
      foreach ($_SESSION["cart"] as $keys => $values) {
        ?>
        <tr>
          <td><?php echo $values["item_name"]; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $values["item_quantity"] ?></td>
          <td>$ <?php echo $values["product_price"]; ?></td>
          <td>$ <?php echo number_format($values["item_quantity"] * $values["product_price"], 2); ?></td>
          <td><a href="shop.php?action=delete&id=<?php echo $values["product_id"]; ?>"><span
                class="text-danger">X</span></a></td>
        </tr>
        <?php
        $total = $total + ($values["item_quantity"] * $values["product_price"]);
      }
      ?>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="3" align="right">Total</td>
        <td align="right">$ <?php echo number_format($total, 2); ?></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <?php
    }
    ?>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just reload the page.

```
<script>window.location.reload()</script>
```

Comment: It keeps on reloading and never stops.